# Workaround with paths in Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, path

I have a `.exe` running in my Windows XP PC.

This `.exe` needs a file in the same directory to run
and has no problem finding it in Windows XP. But, in Windows Vista (I tried this in several machines and works on some of them) fails to run.

I'm guessing there is a problem finding the path.  The program is written in basic (Yes I know..)

I attached the code below.
Can you think of any workarounds?

The `.exe` is located in `C:\tools`
Also the program runs in the Windows console (It starts but then during the execution cannot find a custom file type .TOP made by the creator of the program)

```
     '   PROGRAMM  TOP11.BAS



DEFDBL A-Z
CLS
LOCATE 1, 1
COLOR 14, 1
FOR I = 1 TO 80
   PRINT "±";
NEXT I
LOCATE 1, 35: PRINT "ΝΝ TOP11 ΝΝ"
PRINT "    €€‚—‚„‘ ’— ‹„’†‘„— ‘’† „”€„€ ’†‘ ‡€€‘‘†‘ ‰€ † „.‚.‘.€.     "
COLOR 7, 0
PRINT "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
PRINT
INPUT "ƒι©« «¦¤ ©¬¤«Ά©«γ ¤ΰγ... :  ", Factor#
INPUT "¤¦£ ¨®ε¦¬ [.TOP] : ", topfile$
VIEW PRINT 7 TO 25
file1$ = topfile$ + ".TOP"
file2$ = topfile$ + ".T_P"
file3$ = "Syntel"
OPEN file3$ FOR OUTPUT AS #3
PRINT #3, " ‘¬¤«Ά©«γ ¤ΰγ = " + STR$(Factor#) + "   †‹„‹†€: " + DATE$
CLOSE #3

command1$ = "copy" + " " + file1$ + " " + file2$
SHELL command1$   '’¦ ¨®ε¦ .TOP ¤« ¨α­«  £ «¤ ΅«αΆ¥ .T_P



OPEN file2$ FOR INPUT AS #1
OPEN file1$ FOR OUTPUT AS #2
bb$ = " \\\    \ ,   ###.####   ###.####   ####.###    ##.### "
DO
         LINE INPUT #1, Line$
         Line$ = RTRIM$(LTRIM$(Line$))
         icode$ = LEFT$(Line$, 1)
        IF icode$ = "1" THEN
           Line$ = " " + Line$
           PRINT #2, Line$
           PRINT Line$
        ELSEIF icode$ = "2" THEN
           Line$ = " " + Line$
           PRINT #2, Line$
           PRINT Line$
        ELSEIF icode$ = "3" THEN
             Number$ = MID$(Line$, 3, 6)
             Hangle = VAL(MID$(Line$, 14, 9))
             Zangle = VAL(MID$(Line$, 25, 9))
             Distance = VAL(MID$(Line$, 36, 9))
             Distance = Distance * Factor#
             Height = VAL(MID$(Line$, 48, 6))
           PRINT #2, USING bb$; icode$; Number$; Hangle; Zangle; Distance; Height
           PRINT USING bb$; icode$; Number$; Hangle; Zangle; Distance; Height
         ELSE
        END IF

LOOP UNTIL EOF(1)
VIEW PRINT
CLS
LOCATE 1, 1
PRINT "               ***  ’„‘ ’“ ‚€‹‹€’‘ ***                "
END
```

Comment: Can you provide the path you're using?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Do you mean a DLL file (so the program doesn't even start) or some other file which is read by the program?

Comment: I've not seen BASIC in too long...

Answer (score 0):

Wow!

Well, my first guess would be an [UAC (Use Account Control)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) issue, try right clicking the file and choosing `Run as administrator` and see if it works.